# Showing diagonalization of a Linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like some help or advice with this exercise.

*Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$, and invariant subspaces $U,W \subset V$  such that $V = U \oplus W$. Show that if $T_{|U}, T_{|W}$ are  diagonalizable then $T$ is diagonalizable.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Choose a basis for $V$ first by choosing a basis for $U$ and a basis for $W$. Then the matrix representation of $T$ wrt the given basis for $V$ ( Union of those of $U$ and $W$) will be block diagonal (due to invariance of these subspaces). I guess you are trying to prove a stronger converse of this. The reasoning should be along the same lines.

Comment: The converse is ready!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Take a basis $B_U$ for $U$ and a basis $B_W$ for $W$ in which $T_{|U}$ and $T_{|W}$ have a diagonal matrix. Now let $B=B_U\cup B_W$ a basis for $V$. What's the form of the matrix of $T$ relative to $B$?

Comment: Is correct this form? $$T=\begin{pmatrix} T|_U & 0 \\ 0 & T|_W\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes correct if you mean by $T$ the matrix of $T$ i.e. $[T]$.

Comment: Thanks Sami Ben, I appreciate so much your help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Fix a basis in $U$ and a basis in $V$ in which $T|_U$ and $T|_V$ become diagonal (i.e. take the *eigenvectors* lying in $U$ and $V$, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

if $T_{|U}$ and $T_{|W}$ are diagonalizbale there exist a basis  $\mathcal U$ of $U$ by eigenvectors of $T$ and a basis  $\mathcal W$ of $W$ by eigenvectors of $T$. Then $\mathcal B=\mathcal U \cup \mathcal W$ is a basis of $V$ by eigenvectors of $T$.